# Let $\alpha$ be a real number. Find the value of $\alpha$ for which the given function is continuous and differentiable.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Let $\alpha$ be a real number. Consider the function $$g(x)=(\alpha+|x|)^2e^{(5-|x|)^2}, \ \ \ -\infty<x<\infty  $$
$(i)$ Determine the values of $\alpha$ for which $g$ is continuous at all $x$.
$(ii)$ Determine the values of $\alpha$ for which $g$ is differentiable at all $x$.

---

Directly putting the limit I get that the function is continuous for all $\alpha \in \mathbb R$.
As the function is $$g(x)=(\alpha+x)^2e^{(5-x)^2}, \ \ \ 0\leq x<\infty  $$
and

$$g(x)=(\alpha-x)^2e^{(5+x)^2}, \ \ \ -\infty<x<0  $$
Differintiating these two and putting $x=0$ I get $\alpha=\{0,1/5\}$.
Is my answer correct ?

Comment: Yes. $x=0$ is the only potentially troublesome point. As $x$ tends to 0, the two limits are $\pm2\alpha(5\alpha-1)e^{25}$, so they are only equal if $\alpha=0,\frac{1}{5}$.

Comment: Thank you. Usually 'check my work' questions are not received so well.

Comment: Happy to have helped!